# Can we use 'tslint --fix' command for codelyzer rules?

Tags: angular-cli, nativescript, tslint, codelyzer

Im running this tslint commands:

```
"scripts": {
    "tslint": "tslint -p tsconfig.json",
    "tslint-fix": "tslint --fix -p tsconfig.json"
}
```

**My 'tslint' command is detecting all the rules,it's working fine. But my 'tslint-fix' command only fix tslint rules and ignores codelyzer rules (rulesDirectory).**

There is a way to automate tslint for fixing codelyzer rules?